# How to provide a description or preview for a post (like WordPress)

Tags: tumblr, blog

I would like to put the contents of my Tumblr posts on my website through the API,
but not the entire post, just a preview/description.

Can I manage to do that and if so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While each post does include a `meta description` that contains the first few lines of the post, the `API` doesn't include it in the [documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#text-posts)

I also thought that maybe you could use the automatically created RSS feed to do this, but it looks like they don't include the description there either.

The only way I can see you getting this to work is by snipping off the returned text automatically via your code using their API.

Comment: Oh okay, a post can't have a user edited meta description.
So it's not useful to get this content trough the API...